# Jest not recognizing Yarn workspace module in CircleCI

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg, circleci

My tests run fine locally, but in CircleCI I get this error “Cannot find module ‘shared-data-model’” which is one of my Yarn workspaces.

The stack trace of the error points to `Resolver.resolveModule (../node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:276:11)`

I am running
Jest 25.1.0,
Yarn 1.22,
Node.js 12.16

Any ideas what could be causing this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I am using typescript CLI `tsc` to transpile my module from /src to /dist, and I wasn't running the transpile step on CI to generate the /dist folder, so when it tried to find the entrypoint of the module dist/index.js there was nothing there. Once I ran the build `tsc` step in CI it worked as expected.